# "slip free in one clean piece"

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-choice, phrase-meaning, idiomatic-language, collocations

> When she was five, Harumi lost her parents in a car crash. It was an uncanny collision; a truck crossed over the median into their lane. Harumi was in preschool, rehearsing for a school play. She had no recollection of when she heard the news. She was sure she’d been overwhelmed with sadness, but the memory **had slipped free in one clean piece**. (Source - Higashino: The Miracles of the Namiya General Store)

I figure that "had slipped free in one clean piece" can be paraphrased as "had completely disappeared", but I want to know the exact meaning of the words "free" and "clean" in this context, or this whole phrase is a collocation. Moreover, I know "in one piece" means "[without being hurt or damaged](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20one%20piece)", but that doesn't make much sense here, so I would appreciate some explanation.

Comment: If something 'slips free', it exits, leaves, or escapes; if it does so in 'one clean piece', it escapes completely or totally, and does not leave any part of itself behind.

Comment: This is a translation from Japanese, right? Anyway, this is just literary. A memory is a piece of overall memories that can be dislodged from the brain as a single thing.

Comment: I'm not convinced there's any point in asking questions about the idiomacy of translated text here on ELL. But if we *must* accept them, it would certainly help if we had access to the *original* text, and the benefit of a native speaker of the relevant text to explain exactly what it means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the whole phrase is not a collocation.

*Slipped free* implies that the memory of this traumatic incident had easily 'broken away' from the rest of her memories and disappeared.

A *clean break* is when something breaks leaving straight edges, not jagged or frayed. The author says that it was as though the memory had broken away in a single neat piece.

Comment: We can say that we leave a job, a marriage etc, in a 'clean break' to mean that we take care of all practical matters, so that there are no lingering issues, and there is no implication of blame on either side.

Comment: In this text, a memory is viewed as a piece. Pieces of a memory is certainly understandable in English. I think the piece of memory is viewed as clean, as opposed to murky or suchlike.